# IK Arm rotates in wrong direction

Tags: mesh, rigging, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

After having done my IK rig, I notice that moving my arm control bone moves it **in the wrong direction**. I am not able to put my arm in the correct way.

How I want to pose my arm (sorry, best photo I could find ):

[image]

How it is (tried to pose same as wanted result) :

[image]

I have tried rotating the pole target bone to 0 and other rotations, but this twists the mesh in some gruesome ways :

[image]

Shoul I restart my rig, twist the mesh itself or are there parameters I forgot?

Comment: could you please share your file? (delete all the unnecessary elements) https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I am sending the blend file.

Comment: Here is the file : [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=8WQPXArW" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8WQPXArW/)

Comment: I would not build the armature this way but anyway, I wonder if your problem is not simply because you need to bend the arm a bit in Edit mode, tell me if that fixes the problem

Comment: Can I bend directly the vertices or the armature? - P.S. How would you build the armature? I knwo it is not a human character so the face part might be a bit more complicated

Comment: the armature, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not build the armature this way but anyway, you simply need to bend the arm a bit in *Edit* mode so that Blender knows the correct orientation (same for the legs).

[image]

Comment: I found that the correct angle for the pole would be 90° However if i get to 90° the big deformation on the shoulders is showing up

Comment: IT..... WORKS ! Thank you so much!